# Coq proof for subtraction does not commute

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I would like to prove that subtraction does not commute in Coq but I am stuck.  I believe the that the statement I would like to prove in Coq would be written `forall a b : nat, a <> b -> a - b <> b - a`

Here is what I have for the proof so far.

```
Theorem subtraction_does_not_commute :
  forall a b : nat, a <> b -> a - b <> b - a.
Proof.
  intros a b C.
  unfold not; intro H.
  apply C.
```

I think I could use `C : a <> b` to contradict the goal `a = b`.

Comment: I suggest you prove first WLOG the lemma for `a < b -> a - b <> b -a`. You will need to use induction.

Comment: However there is no special difficulty proving it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use induction on `a`. However, if you start your proof with

```
intros a b C; induction a.
```

you will get stuck because the context will have the following hypotheses:

```
C : S a <> b
IHa : a <> b -> a - b <> b - a
```

You won't be able to use the induction hypothesis `IHa` because one cannot infer the premise of `IHa` (`a <> b`) from `S a <> b`: e.g. `1 <> 0` doesn't imply `0 <> 0`.

But we can make the induction hypothesis stronger by not introducing the variables into the context prematurely:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Lemma subtraction_does_not_commute :
  forall a b : nat, a <> b -> a - b <> b - a.
Proof.
  induction a; intros b C.
  - now rewrite Nat.sub_0_r.
  - destruct b.
    + trivial.
    + repeat rewrite Nat.sub_succ. auto.
Qed.
```

Or, alternatively, using the `omega` tactic, we get a one-line proof:

```
Require Import Omega.

Lemma subtraction_does_not_commute :
  forall a b : nat, a <> b -> a - b <> b - a.
Proof. intros; omega. Qed.
```

Comment: With `omega`, you do not need `induction` at all any more.

Comment: Sure, thanks! Forgot that we are in the realm of Presburger arithmetic in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, works beautifully.  Total noob question how do I find a list of definition and theorem that are avaible like Nat.sub_succ and Nat.sub_0_r?

Comment: @MikeHarris `Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.`, then `Search (S _ - S _).` or `Search (_ - 0).` respectively. Besides the wildcard `_`, Coq's search also understands `Search (?a + ?b = ?b + ?a).` -- this should find `Nat.add_comm`. See [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual008.html#sec248) for more information.